# Magento2: check if url is an admin url

Tags: magento2, admin, redirect, routing

I've 2 websites `UK` (default) and `IN` . I'm using PHP geo-location library to re-direct customers to Indian website based on their IP which is working fine on frontend.

```
$geoipPath = 'lib/geoip/geoip.inc';
require_once($geoipPath);
$gi = geoip_open("lib/geoip/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip);
if(strtoupper($country_code) == "IN"){
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/in/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
else {
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
    $bootstrap->run($app);
}
```

Due to above configuration, admin link is not working.

How I can check in root `index.php` file, if it's an admin url so that it goes to my else statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From index.php, before anything initializes? Realistically, you can't. You could add an explicit check for your admin path in the URL, and skip it if so, but that entire thing makes for a very dirty solution that would just be overwritten every time you upgrade. The easiest solution isn't always best.

You should rewrite your code as a proper Magento module, using an observer or a plugin somewhere in the request routing/dispatching process.

In that context, you'll be able to use dependency injection (DI) to get an instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\State`. The State class contains a method `getAreaCode()`. If the value of that equals `\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML`, then the current request is in the admin panel.

Comment: Thanks. I've got it working using PHP's `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` , `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `strpos()` for the time being. Now I'm going to make it as a separate module.